# Clipping Parent HTML container based on image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to clip an HTML element based on the image inside the HTML element.

How do I go about doing this? I have been searching stackoverflow and could not find an answer.

Here is a more in depth description, my code is set up something like this.

```
<div class="container">
<img src='image.png'/>
<img src='secondimage.png'/>
</div>

.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I want to get the html div container to take the custom shape in image.png. image.png isn't just a basic shape like polygon or rectangle but an organic shape.

I was looking into if there is a way to clip the container if I used clipPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If older browser support is not a concert for you, then I would suggest using [css mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask). An example of usage can be found in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qggRxL). The main difference is that the mask image url is moved from the html markup into the css `mask-image` rule, but this should not be an issue. In case the [current state of support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks) across browsers is insufficient, then using svg filters would be required.
Please note, that the mask feature requires vendor prefixes in webkit browsers (the codepen is configured to run autoprefixer, be sure to do the same)

Comment: Thanks your suggestions worked. I am not too worried about browser compatibility. But your first solution works on the latest version of Firefox.